# Scrapy and XPath issue with nested Xpaths

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to read Amazon products into scrapy.
Starting from a random category using this XPath:

```
products = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="s-item-container"]')
for product in products:
    item = AmzItem()
    item['title'] = product.xpath('//a[@class="s-access-detail-page"]/@title').extract()[0]
    item['url'] = product.xpath('//a[@class="s-access-detail-page"]/@href').extract()[0]
    yield item
```

`('//div[@class="s-item-container"]')` returns all the divs with the products on one category page - that's correct.

Now, how would I get the link to the product?

// stands for where ever in the code
a with the @class should select the right class
But I get a:

`item['title'] = product.xpath('//a[@class="s-access-detail-page"]/@title').extract()[0]
        exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range`

So my list matching this XPath must be empty - but I don't understand why?

EDIT:
The HTML would look like that:

```
<div class="s-item-container" style="height: 343px;">
<div class="a-row a-spacing-base">
    <div class="a-column a-span12 a-text-left">
        <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-inline-block s-position-relative">
            <a class="a-link-normal a-text-normal" href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0105S434A" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><img alt="Product Details" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41%2BzrAY74UL._AA160_.jpg" onload="viewCompleteImageLoaded(this, new Date().getTime(), 24, false);" class="s-access-image cfMarker" height="160" width="160"></a>
            <div class="a-section a-spacing-none a-text-center">
                <div class="a-row a-spacing-top-mini">
                    <a class="a-size-mini a-link-normal a-text-normal" href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0105S434A" rel="nofollow noreferrer">
                        <div class="a-box">
                            <div class="a-box-inner a-padding-mini"><span class="a-color-secondary">See more choices</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="a-row a-spacing-mini">
    <div class="a-row a-spacing-none">
        <a class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  a-text-normal" title="Harry Potter Gryffindor School Fancy Robe Cloak Costume And Tie (Size S)" href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0105S434A" rel="nofollow noreferrer">
            <h2 class="a-size-base a-color-null s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal">Harry Potter Gryffindor School Fancy Robe Cloak Costume And Tie (Size S)</h2>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="a-row a-spacing-mini"><span class="a-size-small a-color-secondary">by </span><span class="a-size-small a-color-secondary">Legend</span></div>
</div>
<div class="a-row a-spacing-mini">
    <div class="a-row a-spacing-none"><a class="a-size-small a-link-normal a-text-normal" href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B0105S434A/ref=sr_1_21_olp?s=pet-supplies&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1435391788&amp;sr=1-21&amp;keywords=pet+supplies&amp;condition=new"><span class="a-size-base a-color-price a-text-bold">$28.99</span><span class="a-letter-space"></span>new<span class="a-letter-space"></span><span class="a-color-secondary">(1 offer)</span><span class="a-letter-space"></span><span class="a-color-secondary a-text-strike"></span></a></div>
</div>
<div class="a-row a-spacing-none"><span name="B0105S434A">
    <span class="a-declarative" data-action="a-popover" data-a-popover="{&quot;max-width&quot;:&quot;700&quot;,&quot;closeButton&quot;:&quot;false&quot;,&quot;position&quot;:&quot;triggerBottom&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;/review/widgets/average-customer-review/popover/ref=acr_search__popover?ie=UTF8&amp;asin=B0105S434A&amp;contextId=search&amp;ref=acr_search__popover&quot;}"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="a-popover-trigger a-declarative"><i class="a-icon a-icon-star a-star-4"><span class="a-icon-alt">3.9 out of 5 stars</span></i><i class="a-icon a-icon-popover"></i></a></span></span>
    <a class="a-size-small a-link-normal a-text-normal" href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0105S434A" rel="nofollow noreferrer">48</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a snippet of the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//a[@class="s-access-detail-page"]` requires to be exactly `class="s-access-detail-page"`, because xpath works with string but not with meaning :) When you have "multi class ", use `contains` function

```
//a[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), " s-access-detail-page ")]/@title
```

Comment: I had to delete the concat part - otherwise I only receive a ` exceptions.ValueError: Invalid XPath` - but now it seems to be working. Got one more issue - not sure whether this comes from that Xpath or sth. else - I'll keep on digging.

Comment: if you carefully done with quotes, it may be problem of xpath realization :(

Comment: Got it working now in several areas - thanks for pointing me into the right direction with the contains.

Comment: Fine! I glad that it helped

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
# ------------- The dot makes the query relative to product
product.xpath('.//a[@class="s-access-detail-page"]/@title')
```

Comment: No - I still receive an empty list with this version.
But I've added my HTML maybe that helps?

Comment: Ok, let me check that

Comment: `a@class="s-access-detail-page"` isn't a child of `div@class="s-item-container"` .. Isn't this obvious?

Comment: Yes, it is. But I don't understand why it doesn't work.
There is only one a with s-access-detail-page - so I can't select it with // or .//. That implies that I need to use the whole path? div/div/a@?
I thought .// or // would be exactly for avoiding adding the whole path?

Comment: The contains was neccessary to select the right path but I used the .// in another area of the HTML and now it working, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit AFK and forgot to respond here. Nice to see that it is working now! :)